# How do you specify __device__ and __forceinline options at the same time?

Tags: templates, methods, cuda, inline

I try to use templated method and additionally to **device** option I would like __forceinline option to be sure a method is actually inlined. However in result I get errors -- no matter what the order of those options are. My code:

```
template<int Begin, int End>
struct Unroller {
    __device__ 
    __forceinline
    static void step(...) {
        ...
```

Comment: doesn't [forceinline](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline) require a double underscore both before and after the keyword?  like this: `__forceinline__`

Comment: @RobertCrovella, you are right, it is unfortunate that there are the same in the meaning but different spelled options in use. Please post your comment as answer (I cannot accept comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[forceinline](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#noinline-and-forceinline) requires a double underscore both before and after the keyword

like this: `__forceinline__`